# -bash: setenv: command not found in cywgin and netcdf libabry is not installling without setenv command

Tags: bash, command, setenv

I want to set an environment variable using SETENVin cwygin64 terminal for NetCDF library. Does anyone know how to perform on WINDOWS equivalent of  SETENV?

Comment: Have you re-run the cygwin setup to see `setenv` package is actually available? There is a chance. If a package requires `setenv` for installing, there is little you could do about it.

Comment: In `bash` you set an environment variable using the `export` command, not `setenv`. `setenv` is a `csh` command.

Comment: Which shell are you running?